# Find text of selected Radio Button

Tags: jquery

this is my dynamically generated html a radio button list

```
<label class="radio" for="10013"><input type="radio" name="himg" value="10013">Amr1a</label> 

<label class="radio" for="10014"><input type="radio" name="himg" value="10014"> Amr2a</label>
```

**Want to select text of clicked(checked) radio button**

this is what I tried(jquery-1.9.1)

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'input:radio[name="himg"]', function () {
                alert($(this).next().text());

            });
```

But it return nothing.

Comment: `alert(this.nextSibling.nodeValue);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
alert($(this).next().text());
```

to:

```
alert($(this).parent().text());
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Pfcn8/)**

You're clicking on the radio button element and then trying to use `.next()` which looks for the next element which there isn't, only a text node. By using `.parent()` you can grab the text within the label (not including the HTML of the radio).

Answer (score 3):

you don't need `body` and `next()` ...`next()` search for next DOM element but in you case that is text..so 
use parent() and `text()`

try this

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:radio[name="himg"]', function () {
            alert($(this).parent().text());

        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:radio[name="himg"]', function () {
    alert($(this).parent().text());
});
```

Actually, the `label` here is the [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) of the selected radio button, not it's immediately following sibling.
So, we need to use `parent()` to get the label element and then it's text.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize `label-for`  by providing the radio ids and assiciating it to the label with the `for` attribute.

[Refer label usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Flabel)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LQV2r/)

#### Html

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="himg" value="10013" />
<label class="radio" for="radio1">Amr1a</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="himg" value="10014" />
<label class="radio" for="radio2">Amr2a</label>
```

#### JS

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'input:radio[name="himg"]', function () {

    alert($('label[for=' + this.id + ']').text()); // Ids are going to be unique so yuo can directly select it with label for.

});
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little tweak in your code, the following should work:

```
   $(document.body).on('click', 'input:radio[name="himg"]', function () {
      alert($(this).closest('label').text());
    });
```